# How to hide API key in JSON API request

Tags: json, api, security

I am creating an API server which serves a card number validation and transaction insert.

Sample API URL = http://mydomain.com/api.json?cardnumber=2342343244&api_key=jhj67asd234tgbh123

**Existing system:**
I am providing an api key to client systems (say ebay.com). I am providing a discount if the user have a valid card. So my client will provide a form field to his end users to enter a valid card number.

**Problem:**
My client is writing ajax request to my domain to process the validation. The problem is the api key is visible in console and anyone can do the request outside of the client system (security loss).

**Propose system:** Please propose a system where my api key is hidden, so that the request will be processed securely. The solution may be any other way of writing an API.

I have less knowledge about API. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any updates on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there isn't an easy way of doing this.

The only method I know about is providing the client with a one-time key. As soon as its used, it expires and the client will need a new one.

In this manner it doesn't matter that the key is visible in the console as its only ever going to be valid for a single request.

I hope that helps but I'd love to hear about any suggestions anyone else has.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But practically it is not possible to provide new Keys to the client at all time. We can send the new API key in the response of a request. But even the new API key will be visible in console.